# Writing a CSV in Java, fails to consistently escape commas

Tags: java, csv, file-io

I'm attempting to create a CSV file in Java that contains the results of a pass/fail query, including if any SQL exceptions occurred.  The issue I'm running into is that I want my failed queries to print out two lines: 1) The original query 2) The error message and its associated query

```
makeCSV("\"" + queries[x] + "\"\n\"" + result + "\"", (x+1));
```

The makeCSV method prints the single string:

```
"\"" + queries[x] + "\"\n\"" + result + "\""
```

where queries[x] is the current query being worked with and result is a message OR parsed result set returned from my DB.

The issue I'm running into is that the first line of the CSV file as the query printed out just fine (with commas escaped).  However the second line is ignoring my escape and separating "result" into 2 columns.  Any ideas why?

Comment: `queries[x]` must already contain the query with commas escaped.  There is no difference in treatment between how the two variables are used in the code you posted

Comment: So you can't escape the comma by including it in a string surrounded by ""?

Comment: No, surrounding it with quotes does only that: surrounds it with quotes.  If you want to escape the spaces, you will have to do that explicitly (e.g. String.replaceAll(",", "\\\\,") to replace all commas with `\,`s)